# Convert variable string to time object

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timedelta, youtube-dl

I'm working with `youtube-dl` (subprocess), it gives the video duration like this:

- if it's **00:00:08**, it gives: `8`.
- **00:03:42** > `3:42`.
- **00:03:08** > `3:08`.
- **01:02:06** > `1:02:06`.

I want to convert the `code` formats to the **bold**!
Tried this but it gives error:

```py
dt.strptime(YT_Duration_str, "%H:%M:%S")

ValueError: time data '8' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Split the output by `:`, then handle the cases with 1, 2 or 3 items in the splitted list separately.

Comment: You don't want a timestamp, since it is a duration. Unless you're always counting from midnight, which is unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```py
n_colons = YT_Duration_str.count(":")

if n_colons == 0:
    d = dt.strptime(YT_Duration_str, "%S")
elif n_colons == 1:
    d = dt.strptime(YT_Duration_str, "%M:%S")
elif n_colons == 2:
    d = dt.strptime(YT_Duration_str, "%H:%M:%S")

d.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

You can also get a `timedelta` object by subtracting:

```py
delta = d - dt.strptime("0", "%S")
```

Comment: Presented string have 2 colons in each option, don't think this could work, Insted can use if statement, if the index wise 0(zeros)

Comment: what if hours are greater than 23 ?

Comment: @MrFuppes - valid point! Not claiming this covers all cases, but the ones in the OP are covered

Comment: Or `dt.strptime(YT_Duration_str, ['%S', '%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S'][n_colons])` :D

Comment: @timgeb - you are quite a packer-unpacker!

Answer (score 2):

Extract the components like this:

```
*rest, hours, minutes, seconds = [0, 0, *map(int, YT_Duration_str.split(':'))]
```

Then create a timedelta object:

```
>>> YT_Duration_str = '01:02:03'
>>> *rest, hours, minutes, seconds = [0, 0, *map(int, YT_Duration_str.split(':'))]
>>> td = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3723)
```

... or some arbitrary datetime

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=hours, minute=minutes, second=seconds, microsecond=0)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3)
>>> dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'01:02:03'
```